# Change of variable in an ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

Consider $Z(s)$ which is a solution to the following ODE:
$$Z''-kZ=ilZ,$$
where $k,l$ are functions of $s$ and $i=\sqrt{-1}.$ Then define, 
$$T(s) = -Z(s)\int_{s}^{s_K}\frac{ds'}{Z^2(s')}.$$
Note that here we assume that $Z$ does not vanish at $s_K.$ Then the author of the paper where these expressions are mentioned states that, $T$ satisfies:
$$T''-kT=ilT.$$
I am not sure if this is the case, since 
$$T' = -Z'\int_{s}^{s_K}\frac{ds'}{Z^2(s')}+\frac{1}{Z} = \frac{Z'T+1}{Z}$$
and so,
$$T''= -Z''\int_{s}^{s_K}\frac{ds'}{Z^2(s')}+\frac{Z'}{Z^2} - \frac{1}{Z^2} =\frac{Z''T}{Z}+\frac{Z'-1}{Z^2} =T(k+il) + \frac{Z'-1}{Z^2}.$$

This is the most I could reduce, I still cannot eliminate $Z'.$ Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: On the face of it, it is impossible to have a T be defined as a function of Z yet both satisfy the same ODE. Right?

Comment: We know the ODE for Z and we want to show that T satisfies the same ODE.